# clearing settings app data causes any future problem?

Tags: applications

i've cleared data from settings app. settings -> apps -> settings app -> clear data.
i've heard a rumor that clearing data of settings app causes os disturbances. 
is that right? please explain.

Comment: Nothing really happens with that action. **Settings** manually modified will be cleared out. That's it. No OS related problems and it won't affect updates from Google.

Answer (score 0):

No that's not a problem clearing the settings data will clear any option you have selected in the settings app

Comment: my friend told me that if I cleared the settings app data it will conflict the future google update and even with OS. is that true?

Comment: you mean to say, settings will be changed to its initial state? that's all? no other problem or risk factors related to os update or os functionality? please reply.

Comment: @Abhi your friend most likely confused that with the *Google Services* app. Clearing data from that one was known to cause disturbances in the past and warned against, though I don't remember the context.

Comment: @Abhi No other problem with functioning of the os  but if you delete data of Google play services or framework then there can be slight problem

Comment: that means, i don't have to worry about it?

Comment: @user170258 No you must not worry about anything